# Does Hybris commerce have price override capability

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

Does Hybris commerce have price override or appeasements capability at Order level or Item level.

Comment: What do you need more precisely ?

Comment: Hi. looking for capability to override particular product price to appease customers in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

There are mulitple ways how that can be done in hybris, one example is using ASM (assisted service module) that offers special promotions that can be granted by a service agent. 
There might also be ways to achieve this using the cs-cockpit (customer service cockpit), I haven't looked into that deeper though.

For ASM documentation look e.g. here: https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8ac06f10866910148d8c850e15b102d2.html

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve. If you like some sort of a discount or promotions, you can see the link provided by Sebastion. In the wiki you can also find other promotion and discount engines. Another solution would be to have multiple price rows per product. Hybris supports this. For example for a particular product, you can set a special price for a special customer or customerGroup. Also the same way you can set different prices for different quantities. For example an apple costs 1$ but if you buy 100, the price goes to 0.75$.

More information about the pricerows: [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/europe1+Pricing+System+Guide)

Keep in mind that Hybris is highly customizable so you can also override some logic from the PriceFactory but i would recommend using first the out of the box price features and then try overriding the PriceFactory.